Why do we intentionally not bless the festival after the haftarah on Shabbat Chol HaMoed Pesach?
On Shabbat Chol haMoed Pesach, all of my Ashkenaz siddurim will tell you to make the regular Shabbat blessing as the final one after the reading of the Haftarah. This is different than the instruction on Shabbat Chol haMoed Sukkot, where one makes a blessing that also includes the festival.
One might initially think this is the same principle or pattern applied as
Why is Hallel different in Sukkot and Pesach (chol ha-moed)? i.e. the ongoing use of lulav and unique sacrifices make Sukkot a special day each day. The Torah service would be consistent in that sense with the Hallel that came before except . . .
Relatively soon afterwards on that same morning, you are going to make that same blessing:
מְקַדֵּשׁ הַשַּׁבָּת וְיִשרָאֵל וְהַזְמַנִּים as you do throughout the festival during Musaf. It is perfectly appropriate thing to say there, but highlights the question: why would that be inappropriate during the Torah service? It makes the explicit choice to only mention Shabbat after the Haftarah look more like an intentional exception.
What is the reason that our tradition is to explicitly not mention the festival at this point?
It also strikes me that this is in some sense different stakes than the question about Hallel. Making a berakah or which one to make is a different, possibly weightier, thing than saying more or fewer Psalms. Is this a misconception?

The stronger question is, I think, why mention the festival in the blessing after the haftara on shabbat chol hamoed sukkot? Yes, it is a festival day, but the haftarah is read only because it is Shabbat, not because of the festival. Consider Shabbat Rosh Chodesh - we mention Rosh chodesh in the musaf blessing, but not haftarah.

@JoelK But we mention Shabbat in Neila and Al Hanisim in musaf. I don't know why one side is stronger than the other a priori. We just need to realize Rosh Chodesh Haftara is part of the same difficult question and not a given that we can learn from.

@DoubleAA I hear you. I think one could develop an approach that posits a reason to mention מעין המאורע in any tefillah or birchat hamazon on a special day, even absent a chiyuv to pray that particular prayer or eat that particular meal. This would then not necessarily apply to a blessing on a haftarah which was never instituted for that type of holiday (maybe similar to me’en sheva on Friday night of yom tov, even though that is much more prayer-like, or not mentioning shabbat in vidui after amidah at Neilah).

@JoelK One could develop an approach for any possible variation, but again none seems so much more obvious a priori.
